# Pass last part of URL into mounted hook

Tags: vue.js, url-parameters

I'm trying to get the product id from the last part of the URL (http://xyz/product/**1234**) which I would like to pass into the mounted hook.

Thanks in advance.

```
mounted() {
UserService.getProductContent("PRODUCT-ID-HERE").then(
  (response) => {
    this.content = response.data;
  },
  (error) => {
    this.content =
      (error.response &&
        error.response.data &&
        error.response.data.message) ||
      error.message ||
      error.toString();
  }
);
```

Comment: What is the setup? The router is expected, and you should have been able to access the parameter through it.

Comment: @EstusFlask Well, I'm pretty new to Vue. I'm using Vue 3. There is no route or router imported on this component if that's what you are asking. I imported a custom js (UserService) in the script part where I have a function that should take the last part of the URL in order to send a GET request to an API and the response should be pushed into an object (ie: data() { return { myObj: ""}} )

Comment: The way you use Vue is the relevant part here, the question should contain it. Is there server side router? Basically you either need to provide a parameter from backend, likely through JS global variables, or parse url in JS.